# asp.net dynamic button fires on second click

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, events, click

I have 2 buttons that is supposed to update the db, and when it updates the page should do a postback with the updated info, however...right now it updates in db alright, but the page doesnt update until the 2nd click, and then the clicks afterwards are alright until i clicked on anohter tab...everything happens all over again...btw the buttons are called up and down, they are dynamically created inside a template that creates the grid

so the up/down button is built right after page_load, the page_load function calls the loaddisplaygrid(or loaddynamicdisplaygrid), then in the loaddisplaygrid(or loaddynamicdisplaygrid) function it builds the template that build the buttons

```
//page load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadToolBarItem textbxItem = MainRadToolBar.Items.FindItemByText("textbox");
    RadTextBox displayName = (RadTextBox)textbxItem.FindControl("displayName");

    Session["UserID"] = getUserID();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Profile.ShowFilter)
        {
            displayMenuBar.Style["display"] = "block";
            displayLineBreak.Style["display"] = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            displayMenuBar.Style["display"] = "none";
            displayLineBreak.Style["display"] = "none";
        }

        loadDisplay();
        loadTemplate(); 
        loadTabs();
        saveDefaultOneOffFilter();
        checkIfEmpty();

        RadTab tab = displayTabs.SelectedTab;
        Profile.CurrTemplate = Profile.DefaultTemplate;
        if (Profile.DefaultTemplate == dfltTempID) //new user
        {
            displayName.Text = User.Identity.Name + "_default";
            si_display_save_button_Click();
            setDefault();
            Profile.CurrTemplate = Profile.DefaultTemplate;
            updateStatsformat();
            Response.Redirect("Display.aspx");
        } 

        if (tab != null)
        {
            loadDisplayGrid(Profile.CurrTemplate);
            Session["SelectedTabID"] = tab.Text;
        }       

    }
    else
    {
        RadTab tab = displayTabs.SelectedTab;

        if (tab != null)
        {
            if (tab.Text == Session["SelectedTabID"].ToString())
            {
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('" + "a" + "');</script>", false);
                loadDynamicDisplayGrid(Profile.CurrTemplate);//needs to be different, special just for postback
            }
            else
            {
                loadDisplayGrid(Profile.CurrTemplate);
                Session["SelectedTabID"] = displayTabs.SelectedTab.Text;
            }
            //automatically saves when toolbar is not visible....
            if (!Profile.ShowFilter) { si_display_save_button_Click(); }
        }

    }
}

 /// <summary>
/// updates and loads the RadGrid for the Display page, depending on which Tab is selected
/// </summary>
private void loadDisplayGrid(int tmpid)
{
    short DType = Convert.ToInt16(displayTabs.SelectedTab.Value);
    GridBoundColumn column;
    GridColumn columnchkbx;
    GridButtonColumn columnUp;
    GridButtonColumn columnDown;
    GridTemplateColumn columntxtbx;
    DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable DisplayGridDT = new DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable();
    DisplayGridTableAdapters.DisplayGridTableAdapter DisplayGridTA = new DisplayGridTableAdapters.DisplayGridTableAdapter();

    //update statsformat for the user if necessary
    if (Profile.CurrTemplate != 0)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDB_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateNewStat", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = getUserID();
        command.Parameters.Add("@tempid", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Profile.CurrTemplate;
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('" + Profile.CurrTemplate + "');</script>", false);
    if (Profile.DefaultTemplate != 0)
    {
        DisplayGridTA.FillBy(DisplayGridDT, DType, (short)tmpid);
    }
    if (DisplayGridDT.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        DisplayGridTA.Fill(DisplayGridDT, getUserID(), DType);
    }

    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Clear();
    //Stat IsDisplayed
    columnchkbx = new GridCheckBoxColumn();
    columnchkbx.HeaderText = "Displayed";
    columnchkbx.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnchkbx);
    //Stats Name
    column = new GridBoundColumn();
    column.HeaderText = "Stats Name";
    column.DataField = DisplayGridDT.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    column.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(column);

    //Invisible columns
    for (int i = 3; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        column = new GridBoundColumn();
        column.HeaderText = (i == 3) ? "StatsTable.Stats_id" : (i == 4) ? "StatsTable.StatsValue_Type" : (i == 5) ? "StatsTable.Stats_CHeader" : "StatsTable.Stats_Desc";
        column.DataField = DisplayGridDT.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        column.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        column.Visible = false;
        StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    //Dynamically created column - Stats Display Format
    columntxtbx = new GridTemplateColumn();

    columntxtbx.HeaderText = "Stats Display Format";
    columntxtbx.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate(DisplayGridDT, getUserID(),Profile.CurrTemplate);

    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columntxtbx);
    /*
    columnArrow = new GridTemplateColumn();
    columnArrow.ItemTemplate = new ArrowTemplate(DisplayGridDT, getUserID(), Profile.CurrTemplate);
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnArrow);*/

    columnUp = new GridButtonColumn();
    columnUp.Text = "↑";
    columnUp.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnUp);

    columnDown = new GridButtonColumn();
    columnDown.Text = "↓";
    columnDown.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnDown);

    StatsFormatGrid.DataSource = DisplayGridDT;
    StatsFormatGrid.DataBind();

    foreach (GridDataItem item in StatsFormatGrid.Items) //sets the properties of IsDisplayed 
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;
        CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)item["IsDisplayed"].Controls[0];
        chkbx.Enabled = true;
        chkbx.AutoPostBack = true;
        String value = row["IsDisplayed"].ToString();
        chkbx.Checked = (value == "True");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the template for GridTemplateColumn in the display page's grid
/// This represent the column DisplayString
/// Three different kinds of contents are used in each cell of the column depending on StatsValue_Type
/// </summary>
private class MyTemplate : ITemplate
{
    //protected RequiredFieldValidator validator1;
    //protected RangeValidator validator2;
    protected TextBox textBox;
    protected DropDownList ddList;
    protected Label txtlb;
    protected Button up;
    protected Button down;
    private DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable MyDT = new DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable();
    private DisplayGridTableAdapters.DisplayGridTableAdapter MyTA = new DisplayGridTableAdapters.DisplayGridTableAdapter();
    private Guid myUserID = new Guid();
    private int template;

    public MyTemplate(DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable DGDT, Guid UserID,int tempid)
    {
        MyDT = DGDT;
        myUserID = UserID;
        template = tempid;
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {

        //textBox = new TextBox();
        ddList = new DropDownList();
        txtlb = new Label();
        up = new Button();
        up.Text = "↑";
        down = new Button();
        down.Text = "↓";
        //textBox.ID = "templateColumnTextBox";
        ddList.ID = "templateColumnDDList";
        txtlb.ID = "txtLabel";
        up.ID = "up";
        down.ID = "down";
        //textBox.DataBinding += new EventHandler(textBox_DataBinding);
        ddList.DataBinding += new EventHandler(ddList_DataBinding);
        txtlb.DataBinding += new EventHandler(label_DataBinding);
        up.Click += new EventHandler(up_Click);
        down.Click += new EventHandler(down_Click);
        /*validator1 = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        validator1.ControlToValidate = "templateColumnTextBox";
        validator1.ErrorMessage = "*";
        validator1.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        validator2 = new RangeValidator();
        validator2.ControlToValidate = "templateColumnTextBox";
        validator2.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
        validator2.MinimumValue = "0";
        validator2.MaximumValue = "12";
        validator2.ErrorMessage = "*0-12";
        validator2.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;*/

        //container.Controls.Add(textBox);
        container.Controls.Add(ddList);
        container.Controls.Add(txtlb);
        container.Controls.Add(up);
        container.Controls.Add(down);

        //container.Controls.Add(validator1);
        //container.Controls.Add(validator2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the text boxes when StatsValue_Type is double or percentage
    /// Assigns the text and the style
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    /*protected void textBox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tBox = (TextBox)sender;

        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)tBox.NamingContainer;
        string displayStr = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString();
        string valType = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[4].ColumnName].ToString();
        string rdm = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString();
        if (valType == "double" || valType == "percentage")
        {
            tBox.Text = displayStr.Remove(displayStr.IndexOf(" "));
            tBox.Font.Bold = true;
            tBox.Style["text-align"] = "center";
            tBox.Width = 70;
            tBox.AutoPostBack = true;
            //tBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(DisplayTextBox_TextChanged);
        }
        else
        {
            tBox.Enabled = false;
            tBox.Visible = false;
        }
    }*/

    protected void up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt = (Button)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)bt.NamingContainer;


        string displayStr = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString();
        string valType = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[4].ColumnName].ToString();
        string rdm = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString();

        int num = Convert.ToInt32(displayStr.Substring(0, displayStr.IndexOf(' ')))+1;
        string updateDisplay = num.ToString() + " decimals";
        string updateVal = "{0:f" + num.ToString() + "}";
        short stats_id = Convert.ToInt16(rdm);
        if (num < 13 && num > -1)
        {
            MyTA.UpdateQuery(updateVal, updateDisplay, stats_id, (short)template);

        }
    }

    protected void down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt = (Button)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)bt.NamingContainer;
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(bt, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('" + "a" + "');</script>", false);
        string displayStr = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString();
        string valType = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[4].ColumnName].ToString();
        string rdm = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString();

        int num = Convert.ToInt32(displayStr.Substring(0, displayStr.IndexOf(' '))) -1;
        string updateDisplay = num.ToString() + " decimals";
        string updateVal = "{0:f" + num.ToString() + "}";
        short stats_id = Convert.ToInt16(rdm);
        if (num < 13 && num > -1)
        {
           MyTA.UpdateQuery(updateVal, updateDisplay, stats_id, (short)template);

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the drop down lists when StatsValue_Type is Date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void ddList_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)dl.NamingContainer;
        string displayStr = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString();
        string valType = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[4].ColumnName].ToString();
        string rdm = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString();
        if (valType == "Date")
        {
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("MM-DD-YY", "{0:MM-dd-yy}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("DD-MM-YY", "{0:dd-MM-yy}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("DD-MMM-YYYY", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"));
            dl.SelectedIndex = (displayStr == "MM-DD-YY") ? 0 : (displayStr == "DD-MM-YY") ? 1 : 2;
            dl.AutoPostBack = true;
            dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DisplayDDList_IndexChanged);
            up.Visible = false;
            down.Visible=false;
        }
        /*else if (valType == "double" || valType == "percentage")
        {
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("1 decimals", "{0:f1}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("2 decimals", "{0:f2}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("3 decimals", "{0:f3}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("4 decimals", "{0:f4}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("5 decimals", "{0:f5}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("6 decimals", "{0:f6}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("7 decimals", "{0:f7}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("8 decimals", "{0:f8}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("9 decimals", "{0:f9}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("10 decimals", "{0:f10}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("11 decimals", "{0:f11}"));
            dl.Items.Add(new ListItem("12 decimals", "{0:f12}"));
            dl.SelectedIndex =Convert.ToInt32(displayStr.Substring(0, displayStr.IndexOf(' ')));
            dl.AutoPostBack = true;
            dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DisplayDDList_IndexChanged);
        }*/
        else
        {
            dl.Enabled = false;
            dl.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the words " digits" after the textboxes when StatsValue_Type is double or percentage
    /// Generates the label with text of DisplayString when StatsValue_Type is bit
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void label_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)lbl.NamingContainer;
        string displayStr = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString();
        string valType = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[4].ColumnName].ToString();
        string rdm = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString();
        if (valType == "bit")
        {
            lbl.Text = displayStr;
            lbl.Font.Bold = true;
            up.Visible = false;
            down.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (valType == "double" || valType == "percentage") { 
            lbl.Text = displayStr;
            lbl.Font.Bold = true;

        }
        else { lbl.Text = ""; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event when textbox is sumbitted
    /// inefficient at the moment because it is fired for every textbox every tab change
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    /*protected void DisplayTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)tb.NamingContainer;

        string textCur = ((TextBox)sender).Text + " decimals";
        string textOld = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString();
        string testing = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[0].ColumnName].ToString();
        if (textCur != textOld)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt16(((TextBox)sender).Text);
            short stats_id = Convert.ToInt16(((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString());
            string format = "{0:f" + value.ToString() + "}";
            string text = value.ToString() + " decimals";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(tb, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('" + "a" + "');</script>", false);
            //MyTA.UpdateDisplayGrid(format, text, myUserID, stats_id);
            MyTA.UpdateQuery(format, text, stats_id, (short)template);
        }
    }*/


    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event when dropdownlist selection changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void DisplayDDList_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem.Text;
        string format = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem.Value;
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridDataItem container = (GridDataItem)ddl.NamingContainer;
        short stats_id = Convert.ToInt16(((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[MyDT.Columns[3].ColumnName].ToString());

        //MyTA.UpdateDisplayGrid(format, date, myUserID, stats_id);
        MyTA.UpdateQuery(format, date, stats_id, (short)template);
    }

}

//this is called on postback
protected void loadDynamicDisplayGrid(int tmpid)
{
    ArrayList oldchkbxList = new ArrayList();
    short DType = Convert.ToInt16(displayTabs.SelectedTab.Value);
    GridBoundColumn column;
    GridColumn columnchkbx;
    GridTemplateColumn columntxtbx;
    GridButtonColumn columnUp;
    GridButtonColumn columnDown;
    //GridTemplateColumn columnArrow;
    DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable DisplayGridDT = new DisplayGrid.DisplayGridDataTable();
    DisplayGridTableAdapters.DisplayGridTableAdapter DisplayGridTA = new DisplayGridTableAdapters.DisplayGridTableAdapter();

    //update statsformat for the user if necessary
    if (Profile.CurrTemplate != 0)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDB_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateNewStat", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = getUserID();
        command.Parameters.Add("@tempid", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Profile.CurrTemplate;
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    if (Profile.DefaultTemplate != 0)
    {
        DisplayGridTA.FillBy(DisplayGridDT, DType, (short)tmpid);
    }
    if (DisplayGridDT.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        DisplayGridTA.Fill(DisplayGridDT, getUserID(), DType);
    }

    //save the old values of the IsDisplayed checkboxes before refresh
    foreach (GridDataItem item in StatsFormatGrid.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)item["IsDisplayed"].Controls[0];
        oldchkbxList.Add(chkbx.Checked);
    }

    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Clear();
    //Stat IsDisplayed
    columnchkbx = new GridCheckBoxColumn();
    columnchkbx.HeaderText = "Displayed";
    columnchkbx.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnchkbx);
    //Stats Name
    column = new GridBoundColumn();
    column.HeaderText = "Stats Name";
    column.DataField = DisplayGridDT.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    column.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(column);

    //Invisible columns
    for (int i = 3; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        column = new GridBoundColumn();
        column.HeaderText = (i == 3) ? "StatsTable.Stats_id" : (i == 4) ? "StatsTable.StatsValue_Type" : (i == 5) ? "StatsTable.Stats_CHeader" : "StatsTable.Stats_Desc";
        column.DataField = DisplayGridDT.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        column.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        column.Visible = false;
        StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    //Dynamically created column - Stats Display Format
    columntxtbx = new GridTemplateColumn();
    columntxtbx.HeaderText = "Stats Display Format";
    columntxtbx.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate(DisplayGridDT, getUserID(),Profile.CurrTemplate);
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columntxtbx);
    /*
    columnArrow = new GridTemplateColumn();
    columnArrow.ItemTemplate = new ArrowTemplate(DisplayGridDT, getUserID(), Profile.CurrTemplate);
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnArrow);*/

    columnUp = new GridButtonColumn();
    columnUp.Text = "↑";
    columnUp.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnUp);

    columnDown = new GridButtonColumn();
    columnDown.Text = "↓";
    columnDown.UniqueName = DisplayGridDT.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    StatsFormatGrid.Columns.Add(columnDown);

    StatsFormatGrid.DataSource = DisplayGridDT;
    StatsFormatGrid.DataBind();


    int itr = 0;
    foreach (GridDataItem item in StatsFormatGrid.Items) //sets the properties of IsDisplayed 
    {
        CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)item["IsDisplayed"].Controls[0];
        chkbx.Enabled = true;
        chkbx.AutoPostBack = true;
        chkbx.Checked = (Boolean)oldchkbxList[itr];

        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;
        String value = row["IsDisplayed"].ToString();
        if (value == "True" && !(Boolean)oldchkbxList[itr])
        {
            DisplayedCheckbox_CheckedChanged(chkbx, DisplayGridDT);
        }
        else if (value != "True" && (Boolean)oldchkbxList[itr])
        {
            DisplayedCheckbox_CheckedChanged(chkbx, DisplayGridDT);
        }
        itr++;
    }
}

//this is html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="StatsFormatGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                OnDataBound="grid_data_bound" EnableAJAX="true">
                <%--ClientSettings>
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                </ClientSettings--%>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: If you set breakpoints, are you able to hit all of them in your page_load and up_Click/down_Click methods?

Comment: this might be possible due to focus problems, have the same problems with some comboboxes of mine.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the load event. If, the first time you click the button, this is called, but not your button event handler, it's because you added the button too late in the original requests page lifecycle. This first click then "wires" the button up for the second click.

You can also test this by moving the code that adds/shows/wires up the button to the page to the init event.

Comment: Please make your intro text more readable by splitting it into several sentences and correcting the typos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are having a common problem with databinding and the [ASP.net Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Simply put: you first databind the data and then you change it. The `Page_Load` event handler binds your data, after that the press of the button is handled and it changes the database. However, the control is already bound to a previous version of the data and displays old information.

You should databind your control **AFTER** the button press has been handled and the change in the database has been processed. Try putting your databinding code in the `Page_PreRender` event handler.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you, ur a god, u just saved my life!!!! aahhhh.....all i added was `protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
        loadDynamicDisplayGrid(Profile.CurrTemplate);
    }`

Comment: hahaha good, I'm glad you managed to solve the issue. Bookmark that page `ASP.net Page Life Cycle`, it might save you again in the future. It saved me several times already. :)

Comment: oh i'll bookmark it, print it out, put it in a picture frame, and read it like a bible

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

after finish updating database in button click event.

Or call functions that init data in your page. For example

```
private void Page_Load(...)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        InitData();
    }
}

private void InitData()
{
    //Do init data control in your page
    // For exp: binding the grid, combo box....
}

protected void btn_Update_Clicked(...)
{
    //1. Update database
    //2. Call InitData() function to reload data from database
}
```

Comment: i put `bt.PostBackUrl = "~/traders/Preference/Display.aspx"; ` after the click event, but it doesn't get called until the 2nd click, (im a bit new, i tried to put `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` but the click is inside a template and it doesn't find 'Response.blabla'..i edited the code i posted cuz i forgot to post a part of the code..so this button is built right after page_load, the page_load function calls the loaddisplaygrid(or loaddynamicdisplaygrid), then in the loadgrids function it calls the template and build the buttons